# KendoUI datasource: parseInt of filter value

Tags: parsing, filter, datasource, kendo-ui

I need to filter a Kendo datasource through the following filter item object:

```
filters: [
    {
        field: "FIELD", 
        operator: "lt", 
        value: "080"
    }
]
```

That means, because of the way data are transmitted, I am trying to test a case like: "013" < "080".

But it does not work out of the box.

Is there a way to define a filter with something like a "parseInt" on the tested values?
Thank you!

Comment: What does not work mean? `013` is not less than `080`? `13` is not less that `080`?

Comment: Yes it is, I was saying that the filter on the datasource does not work if I prefix the value with "0". '"13" lt "80"' return true, but '"013" lt "080"' does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `FIELD` as a number in `model`:

```
schema  : {
    model: {
        fields: {
            FIELD : { type: "number" }
        }
    }
},
```

If you do so, then `FIELD` is displayed as 13, 80,... If you want to display `FIELD` with leading `0`, use the following in the `column` definition of the grid.

```
{ field: "FIELD", title: "Field", format: "{0:000}" }
```

Doing this `FIELD` is considered as a number even that it is displayed as 013, 080...

You should have something like:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data    : entries,
    batch   : true,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                FIELD: { type: "number" }
            }
        }
    }
});

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns   : [
        { field: "FIELD", title: "Field", format: "{0:000}" }
    ],
    filterable: true
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

If you want to try it, see it in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/HHAS7/1/)

EDIT: Updated code for using `format` instead of `template` as Mateo Piazza suggested

Comment: Thanx, you are right: I guess I use a solution similar to yours, but formatting the field for visualization through the "format" option parameter in the grid.

Comment: I've updated the example using `format` instead of `template` since it is simpler. Good idea @MatteoPiazza!

Comment: Yes, indeed it is. This way I could use templates for more complex, or just different, requirements.

Comment: Just for curiosity: do you know how to define a fitler "operator" as a function? I understand it should be defined as operator: function(item, value) {...}, but what should it return? A "true" or "false" result of comparison?